# How to link extra documentation and examples for individual functions in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I would like to produce documentation similar to [this](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/mw/Network/html/group__tcp__user__api.html) page. Basically, they have both the API reference, explanations and example code in one page. The example code and further explanation of each function aren't in the header file where the function definition is contained, so I don't really understand how they do that.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: probably by means of \code or \example

Comment: In the header file it just contains the parameters, there is no \code or \example. Could it be that the example and diagrams etc are contained in the original c file?

Comment: This might be the case.